# Checking SUM and ignoring zero values?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of transaction details that I'm trying to compile into one sum per transaction. Below is an image of some example rows. The detail_id is not needed, just there to show the details.

[image: Row Examples]

I'm looking to compile the total by the tran_num while ignoring the `collections_go_to` column (I need the ID for end results), but only if the `adjustment_id`, `resp_party_id`, `date_entered`, and 'location' match the other row with the `tran_num`

Which I realize can be easily accomplished with GROUP BY. What my question is, how would I do a check prior that essentially looks to see if:
SUM(amount) <> 0 where the `tran_num` and `location` match:

[image: Ignore Total]

So that rows like this can be totaled and then ignored due to being zero value?

```
SELECT tran_num, resp_party_id, collections_go_to, SUM(amount) AS Total, 
    adjustment_id, type, impacts, clinic, date_entered
FROM dbo.transactions
WHERE (status <> 'D')
  AND (status <> 'V')
  AND (adjustment_id IS NOT NULL)
  AND (date_entered > '2015-06-01')
GROUP BY
     tran_num, resp_party_id,
     collections_go_to, adjustment_id,
     type, impacts, clinic, date_entered
```

This is currently a view of the data that I'm using, I'm ignoring the `paytype_id` column for the moment.

EDIT UPDATE: Thanks for the replies, the HAVING clause does seem to be the way to handle some of this but unfortunately the `collections_go_to` column needs to be ignored for the calculation check else I just end up with multiple results for the `tran_num`. Is there a way to essentially do a sub-query to do a check without the `collections_go_to` column to eliminate any `tran_num` that result in zero but I still need the `collections_go_to` ID. Perhaps seeing which `tran_num` total is zero and then pull those IDs out of the end results

Comment: Look into the HAVING clause

Answer (score 3):

via: having

```
  SELECT tran_num, resp_party_id, collections_go_to, SUM(amount) AS Total, 
         adjustment_id, type, impacts, clinic, date_entered
  FROM dbo.transactions
  WHERE (status <> 'D')
    AND (status <> 'V')
    AND (adjustment_id IS NOT NULL)
    AND (date_entered > '2015-06-01')
  GROUP BY
    tran_num, resp_party_id,
    collections_go_to, adjustment_id,
    type, impacts, clinic, date_entered
  Having sum(amount) <> 0
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the HAVING clause, wrap your query as a subquery like this:

```
SELECT tran_num, resp_party_id, collections_go_to, Total, 
        adjustment_id, type, impacts, clinic, date_entered
FROM (
    SELECT tran_num, resp_party_id, collections_go_to, SUM(amount) AS Total, 
        adjustment_id, type, impacts, clinic, date_entered
    FROM dbo.transactions
    WHERE (status <> 'D')
      AND (status <> 'V')
      AND (adjustment_id IS NOT NULL)
      AND (date_entered > '2015-06-01')
    GROUP BY
         tran_num, resp_party_id,
         collections_go_to, adjustment_id,
         type, impacts, clinic, date_entered
)T
WHERE T.Total <> 0
```

Although this usage here seems trivial, this is a very powerful technique in general. One can also use a CTE for the identical effect (with the bonus of improved readability):

```
;WITH T as (
    SELECT tran_num, resp_party_id, collections_go_to, SUM(amount) AS Total, 
        adjustment_id, type, impacts, clinic, date_entered
    FROM dbo.transactions
    WHERE (status <> 'D')
      AND (status <> 'V')
      AND (adjustment_id IS NOT NULL)
      AND (date_entered > '2015-06-01')
    GROUP BY
         tran_num, resp_party_id,
         collections_go_to, adjustment_id,
         type, impacts, clinic, date_entered
)
SELECT tran_num, resp_party_id, collections_go_to, Total, 
        adjustment_id, type, impacts, clinic, date_entered
FROM T
WHERE T.Total <> 0
```